# Writing query using SELF JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Alias name has given which differentiates the two copies of the table.
How to combine the following three queries into one?. I need to create a menu using these data. Hierarchical data structure like follow for e.g Country -> State -> Cites.

Following are the columns int the table:

```
           [ID]
          ,[Type]
          ,[ParentID]
          ,[Title]
          ,[Name]
          ,[ZoneName]
          ,[TemplateKey]
          ,[TranslationKey]
          ,[Created]
          ,[Updated]
          ,[Published]
          ,[Expires]
          ,[SortOrder]
          ,[Visible]
          ,[VersionOfID]
          ,[SavedBy]
          ,[AncestralTrail]
          ,[VersionIndex]
          ,[State]
          ,[ChildState]
          ,[AlteredPermissions]

SELECT a.[ID],a.[Type],a.[ParentID],a.[Title],b.[ID],b. [Type],b.[ParentID],b.[Title], a.[AncestralTrail] 
FROM [n2Item] a, [n2Item] b
WHERE a.[ID] = b.[ParentID] AND a.Title = 'Holidays'  AND b.[Type] = 'StorefrontPage' 
ORDER BY b.[Title] ,A.[ParentID],a.[SortOrder];
```

Result: 
810, HomePage, 1, Holidays, 5531, StorefrontPage, 810, Canada, /1/

```
SELECT a.[ID],a.[Type],a.[ParentID],a.[Title],b.[ID],b. [Type],b.[ParentID],b.[Title], a.[AncestralTrail] 
FROM [n2Item] a, [n2Item] b 
WHERE a.[id] = b.[ParentID] AND a.Title = 'Canada'  
ORDER BY b.[Title] ,A.[ParentID],a.[SortOrder];
```

Result:
5531, StorefrontPage, 810, Canada, 6132, ImportedPage, 5531, 2014 Special Offers, /1/810/

```
SELECT a.[ID],a.[Type],a.[ParentID],a.[Title],b.[ID],b. [Type],b.[ParentID],b.[Title], a.[AncestralTrail] 
FROM [n2Item] a, [n2Item] b 
WHERE a.[id] = b.[ParentID] AND a.Title = 'Vancouver'  
ORDER BY b.[Title] ,A.[ParentID],a.[SortOrder];
```

Result:
5542, StorefrontPage, 5531, Vancouver, 6365,ImportedPage, 5542, Alaska Cruise and Vancouver Stay, /1/810/5531/
5542, StorefrontPage, 5531, Vancouver, 6368, ImportedPage, 5542, Best Western Plus Sands Hotel, /1/810/5531/

Comment: You can `Union all` to combine them - as a condition you need to have same number of columns returned by all these 3 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT a.[ID], a.[Type], a.[ParentID], a.[Title], b.[ID], b.[Type], b.[ParentID], b.[Title],
       a.[AncestralTrail] 
FROM [n2Item] a JOIN
     [n2Item] b
     ON a.[ID] = b.[ParentID]
WHERE a.Title IN ('Canada', 'Vancouver') OR
      (a.Title = 'Holidays' AND b.[Type] = 'StorefrontPage')
ORDER BY b.[Title] ,A.[ParentID],a.[SortOrder];
```

This just combines the separate logic in the `WHERE` clause (after doing an explicit join).